# URI segments, 2 segment codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I want my url to be like this: www.app.com/projects/projectnumber

But from what I'm reading in the docs, I need to specify three segments to send in an parameter?

So I get www.app.com/projects/**index**/projectnumber. Is there anyway I can do this with just two segments so I can get rid off "index"?

Comment: domain.com/controller/method/parameter1/parameter2/etc... to tweak this, use routes.php and/or .htaccess

Answer (score 1):

you can try this

```
$route['projects/(:num)'] = "projects/index/$1";
```

https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html